# Как это может работать, тем более, правильно?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

У меня есть программа:

```
    uses crt;
    var num:byte;
        str:string;

    procedure crypt(str:string);
    var k:integer;
    begin
        clrscr;
        writeln('In start: ',str);
        for k:=1 to length(str) do begin
             if (ord(str[k])+2>90) and (ord(str[k])+2<93) then chr(ord(str[k])):=chr(ord(str[k])-26);
             if ord(str[k])+2>122 then chr(ord(str[k])):=chr(ord(str[k])-26);
            str[k]:=chr(ord(str[k])+2);
        end;
        writeln('In end: ', str);
    end;

    begin
        repeat
             writeln('Select action');
             writeln();
             writeln('0 - exit');
             writeln('1 - crypt');
             writeln('2 - decrypt');
             writeln();
             write('Choice: ');
             readln(num);
             clrscr;
             writeln('Enter text:');
             readln(str);

             case num of
                 1: crypt(str);
                 2: decrypt(str);
             end;
             readln();
             clrscr;
        until num= 0;
    end.
```

Почему работают эти строки? Этого же не может быть!!! Нельзя присвоить возвращаемому значению функции `chr` возвращаемое значение этой же функции, только с другим аргументом!

```
 if (ord(str[k])+2>90) and (ord(str[k])+2<93) then chr(ord(str[k])):=chr(ord(str[k])-26);
 if ord(str[k])+2>122 then chr(ord(str[k])):=chr(ord(str[k])-26);
```

Comment: @Visman, делает то, что нужно — заменяет символ (это должно было присваиваться символу строки, но так вышло, что я это присваиваю... символу, который возвращает функция `chr`).

Comment: А паскаль у вас какой?

Comment: @Visman, эм... Обычный. Компилятор FreePascal.

Comment: Если `chr(ord(str[k])):=` в обеих строках заменить на `str[k]:=`, то после шифровки текст будет такой же как и при шифровании первым способом?

Comment: @Visman, хм... Да.

Comment: Какой у Вас "правильный", а самое главное "чистый" код. Я восхищен.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, писал не я, так что претензии тоже не ко мне. Хотя на Java у меня такая каша..

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположу, что правильнее и понятнее было бы записать вот так:

```
str[k] := chr(ord(str[k])-26);
```

Т.е. без двойного преобразования `Char -> Byte -> Char`

---

**UPD**: Читаем [справку на Freepascal](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/chr.html) по "функции" `chr`:

> Originally, Pascal did not have typecasts and chr was a necessary
>   function in order to do certain operations on ASCII values of
>   characters. With the arrival of typecasting a generic approach became
>   possible, making chr mostly obselete. However, chr is not considered
>   deprecated and remains in wide use today.

Т.е. `chr` в данном контексте не функция, а преобразование типа `Byte -> Char`

---

**UPD2**: Возможно оптимизатор компилятора просто "выбросил" двойное преобразование типов.

Comment: Тут вопрос не в правильности, а в том что работает неправильный код и работает как надо.

Comment: А вот эта конструкция `chr(ord(str[k]))` не двойное приведение типов? Если так, то все ок, код правильный.

Comment: так вот в этом вопрос и состоит: почему присвоение значения результату функции изменяет значение аргумента от которого она вычисляется.

Comment: @Visman дополнил ответ